# Setting header for notify file content changed. PHP, Twilio

Tags: php, http-headers, twilio

I'm working on a twilio project with PHP which will be playing back a frequently changing audio file.

Twilio's TwiML Voice [documentation](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) states to:

> make sure your web server is sending the proper headers to inform us
>   that the contents of the file have changed

Which headers are these and how do I set them in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**Which headers are these?**

This is how caching works on Twilio

- Twilio requests a .mp3 from your server using a GET request. Your
  server sends back a 200 OK, and also sends back an E-Tag header.
  Twilio will save the E-Tag header, as well as the mp3 file, in its
  database.
- The next time Twilio sends a GET request to that URL, it will send
  along the E-Tag header (it should look like "If-None-Match"). If the
  file has not changed since the last time Twilio accesses it, your
  server will send back a 304 Not Modified header. Crucially, it will
  not send the mp3 file data. Twilio will use the mp3 file it has
  stored in its database. It's much faster for Twilio to read the mp3
  file from its database than it is for your server to send it (and it
  also saves your server bandwidth).
- If you change the content of the mp3 that is being served at the URL,
  and Twilio makes a GET request to the URL, then your server will send
  back a 200 OK, with a new E-Tag. Twilio will download the file from
  your server, and cache it.

**How do I set them in PHP?**

`header("ETag: \"uniqueID\");`

When sending a file, web server attaches ID of the file in header called **ETag**. When requesting file, browser checks if the file was already downloaded. If cached file is found, server sends the ID with the file request to server. Server checks if the IDs match and if they do, sends back `header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");` else Server sends the file normally.

One easy way to check is by adding some fake key-value pairs to the end of the URL, like http://yoururl.com/play.mp3?key=somevalue. Your website should still serve the same mp3 as it would if you loaded example.com/test.mp3, but to Twilio it will appear to be a new URL (uncached).

Answer (score 0):

Twilio uses Squid to cache MP3. You can control how long an item is cached using the cache control header.

cache-control: max-age=3600

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InnerWorkings#How_does_Squid_decide_when_to_refresh_a_cached_object.3F